# K8s Cluster Autoscaler on Self-Managed Kubernetes setup on AWS: no node group config

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, autoscaling, microk8s

I have a cluster with an autoscaling group and I am using Microk8s on the K8s nodes. I deployed the following K8s-cluster autoscaler:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-addon: cluster-autoscaler.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: cluster-autoscaler
  name: cluster-autoscaler
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cluster-autoscaler
  labels:
    k8s-addon: cluster-autoscaler.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: cluster-autoscaler
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["events", "endpoints"]
    verbs: ["create", "patch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/eviction"]
    verbs: ["create"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/status"]
    verbs: ["update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["endpoints"]
    resourceNames: ["cluster-autoscaler"]
    verbs: ["get", "update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["nodes"]
    verbs: ["watch", "list", "get", "update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - "namespaces"
      - "pods"
      - "services"
      - "replicationcontrollers"
      - "persistentvolumeclaims"
      - "persistentvolumes"
    verbs: ["watch", "list", "get"]
  - apiGroups: ["extensions"]
    resources: ["replicasets", "daemonsets"]
    verbs: ["watch", "list", "get"]
  - apiGroups: ["policy"]
    resources: ["poddisruptionbudgets"]
    verbs: ["watch", "list"]
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources: ["statefulsets", "replicasets", "daemonsets"]
    verbs: ["watch", "list", "get"]
  - apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"]
    resources:
      ["storageclasses", "csinodes", "csidrivers", "csistoragecapacities"]
    verbs: ["watch", "list", "get"]
  - apiGroups: ["batch", "extensions"]
    resources: ["jobs"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "patch"]
  - apiGroups: ["coordination.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["leases"]
    verbs: ["create"]
  - apiGroups: ["coordination.k8s.io"]
    resourceNames: ["cluster-autoscaler"]
    resources: ["leases"]
    verbs: ["get", "update"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: cluster-autoscaler
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-addon: cluster-autoscaler.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: cluster-autoscaler
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    verbs: ["create", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    resourceNames:
      ["cluster-autoscaler-status", "cluster-autoscaler-priority-expander"]
    verbs: ["delete", "get", "update", "watch"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cluster-autoscaler
  labels:
    k8s-addon: cluster-autoscaler.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: cluster-autoscaler
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-autoscaler
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: cluster-autoscaler
    namespace: kube-system

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cluster-autoscaler
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-addon: cluster-autoscaler.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: cluster-autoscaler
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: cluster-autoscaler
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: cluster-autoscaler
    namespace: kube-system

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cluster-autoscaler
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: cluster-autoscaler
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cluster-autoscaler
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cluster-autoscaler
    spec:
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 65534
        fsGroup: 65534
      serviceAccountName: cluster-autoscaler
      containers:
        - image: k8s.gcr.io/autoscaling/cluster-autoscaler:v1.23.0
          name: cluster-autoscaler
          env:
            - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              value: eu-west-1
            - name: AWS_REGION
              value: eu-west-1
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 600Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 600Mi
          command:
            - ./cluster-autoscaler
            - --v=4
            - --stderrthreshold=info
            - --cloud-provider=aws
            - --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
            - --expander=least-waste
            - --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled,k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/GP-ARM-ASG
          volumeMounts:
            - name: ssl-certs
              mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
              readOnly: true
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
      volumes:
        - name: ssl-certs
          hostPath:
            path: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

And I get these errors: `Node ip-10-0-0-78 should not be processed by cluster autoscaler (no node group config)`

But the node in question has these EC2 tags:

```
1. k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled    true
2. k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/GP-ARM-ASG owned
3. k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/node-template/label/type   gp
4. kubernetes.io/cluster/GP-ARM-ASG owned
```

I added 3 because I need the hint that these nodes will have different specs so I am using the label type=gp for that.

I also added 4 because of this AWS EKS documentation, hoping that that would solve the 'no node group config' error.

After 10 minutes of a node joining the cluster it does not get scaled down (the desired state of the ASG doesn't get changed) and I think that this is due to the fact that there is this error.

The ASG has the tags and is set to propagate on launch so each individual EC2 has the tags as well.

Can anyone provide some help on this?

Comment: FYI k8s autoscaler doesn't generally work great with a cluster of mixed spec instances. AWS recently released https://karpenter.sh/ which doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: @jordanm but i am not understanding the error itself, or better: what is missing. I understand there may be problems with instance types but still the error is odd because every bit of information I find seems to point the point to be the tags but the tags are correct...